# Using variables in scriptblock and here-string

Tags: powershell, scriptblock, herestring

I started a script with script-block:

```
[scriptblock]$HKCURegistrySettings = {
        Set-RegistryKey -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common' -Name 'qmenable' -Value 0 -Type DWord -SID $UserProfile.SID
        Set-RegistryKey -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common' -Name 'updatereliabilitydata' -Value 1 -Type DWord -SID $UserProfile.SID
        Set-RegistryKey -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce' -Name 'blabla' -Value 1 -Type DWord -SID $UserProfile.SID
    }
```

So this is what it must look.

OK, but I need a variable.

```
$HKCURegistrySettings2 = {
@"

        set-RegistryKey -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common' -Name 'qmenable' -Value 0 -Type DWord -SID $UserProfile.SID
        Set-RegistryKey -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common' -Name 'updatereliabilitydata' -Value 1 -Type DWord -SID $UserProfile.SID
        Set-RegistryKey -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce' -Name `'$test`' -Value 1 -Type DWord -SID $UserProfile.SID
"@
}
```

So I replace `blabla` by `$test`.

```
$test="blabla"
$test3=&$HKCURegistrySettings2
$test3

[ScriptBlock]$HKCURegistrySettings3 = [ScriptBlock]::Create($test3)
```

`$HKCURegistrySettings -eq $HKCURegistrySettings3`

So now by comparing my first `$HKCURegistrySettings` and my now `$HKCURegistrySettings3`

They should be the same. But I get a false.
1. Why are they different?
2. How may I get to make them identical?
3. The variables are define AFTER the Here-strings creation. Other option?

When the scriptblock is create it is then use to call a function
Initially:

```
Invoke-HKCURegistrySettingsForAllUsers -RegistrySettings $HKCURegistrySettings
```

and now

```
Invoke-HKCURegistrySettingsForAllUsers -RegistrySettings $HKCURegistrySettings3
```

So this is why the result should be the same.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`HKCURegistrySettings2` expands other variables too, so `$test3` string no longer has `$UserProfile.SID`, it's been expanded. Compare the contents yourself by running `"$HKCURegistrySettings"` and `"$HKCURegistrySettings3"` in the PS command prompt.

You can escape those variables that don't need expansion by using `` `$ `` instead of `$`:

```
$HKCURegistrySettings2 = {
@"

        set-RegistryKey -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common' -Name 'qmenable' -Value 0 -Type DWord -SID `$UserProfile.SID
        Set-RegistryKey -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common' -Name 'updatereliabilitydata' -Value 1 -Type DWord -SID `$UserProfile.SID
        Set-RegistryKey -Key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce' -Name `'$test`' -Value 1 -Type DWord -SID `$UserProfile.SID
"@
}
```

And then compare the trimmed contents:

```
"$HKCURegistrySettings".trim() -eq "$HKCURegistrySettings3".trim()
```

> True

Answer (score 0):

Your ScriptBlock can take parameters, just like a function.   For example:

```
$sb = { param($x) $a = 'hello'; echo "$a $x!"; }
& $sb 'Powershell'
```

Should print `Hello Powershell!`